# How to put API key into Youtube.Builder in Youtube's Android API?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to retrieve a Youtube Channel in an Android app, and has below code:

```
HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential()
        .setAccessToken("<my api key>");
YouTube yt = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory,
        credential).build();
try {
    List l = yt.channels().list("id");
    l.put("id", "UCO3bfz4KY6zGT5IOaFJuxpA");
    ChannelListResponse resp = l.execute();
    java.util.List<Channel> chs = resp.getItems();
    for (Channel ch : chs) {
        // ...
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I got error response message `"Invalid Credentials"`. I am using the API key in `https://console.developers.google.com/project/<project name>/apiui/credential`, segmentation of `Public API access`, `API KEY`.

I am not sure I'm using wrong key, wrong API, setting up wrong, should not run with debug key, or something other wrong. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the method is in the `List`.

```
List l = yt.channels().list("id");
l.setKey("<Browser API Key");  // This line
l.put("id", "UCO3bfz4KY6zGT5IOaFJuxpA");
```

Note that don't use Android API Key here since it's for Player API, not Data API. I need to create a new browser key with empty refer limitation to make things work.

See a full Java code example on Google's YouTube > Data API website using `setKey()`:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#examples